# Spring Boot base Docker image - good idea?

Tags: spring-boot, docker

recently some peers had the idea of creating a Spring Boot base Docker image. The reasoning is that way they could control the version, perform updates for security, etc.

Is it a good idea? Is there already a good, updated image you would suggest? I searched on dockerhub and didn't see one that's updated.

Thanks!

This is a philosophical question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is none because this doesn't make sense, Spring Boot is an application framework, you cannot package it into a docker image as the framework itself isn't runnable. You can package an application built on top of Spring Boot in a docker image though. But how would you use that as a base for other images?

Comment: Yeah that's what I was thinking. I'm trying to make sense of the request and I really can't, so I thought I'd ask the community.